# How to remove GET params with AngularJS?

Tags: get, angularjs, url-routing

```
#/order/123?status=success
```

hits the route `'/order/:id'` and takes to `OrderCtrl`.

Once we access the `$routeParams.query`, we want to clear the url to `#/order/123`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the `$location` service, you can remove the search param by assigning it a null value:

```js
$location.search( 'status', null );
```

But you should note that, by default, this will reload the current route. If you don't want to reload the current route, you can disable that in your route definition:

```js
$routeProvider.when( '/order/:id', {
  // yada yada...
  reloadOnSearch: false
});
```

But the `$routeUpdate` will still fire and can be reacted to.

Comment: Great! This seems to work with $location.search( 'status', null ).replace() as well.

Answer (score 12):

A more efficient way to remove all search params would probably be

```
$location.search({});
```