# Hide URL parameters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, anchor

I am pretty new to AngularJS.
My question is regarding Hiding paramters in URL.

For Example, i have an URL Like,

```
http://localhost:8080/CareerTurn/#/viewExamwiseStudentsReport?exam_id=2&eName=College%20Model%20Exam&mMarks=10&time=00:10
```

I want to show this like,

```
http://localhost:8080/CareerTurn/#/viewExamwiseStudentsReport
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#viewExamwiseStudentsReport?exam_id={{exa.model_exam_id}}&eName={{exa.model_exam_name}}&mMarks={{exa.model_exam_total_marks}}&time={{exa.model_exam_duration}}">
```

I don't want to show parameters in URL but i want to use them in my JS Controller,

How to achieve it?

Comment: are you using ui-route or ng-route

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove GET params with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526947/how-to-remove-get-params-with-angularjs)

Comment: @sachilaranawaka ng-route.. have any better opinion or suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$location.url($location.path());
```

Also

If you want to remove ALL query parameters, do:

```
$location.search({});
```

If you want To remove ONE particular query parameter, do:

```
$location.search('ParamName', null);
```

Comment: what if im using like this in a HTMl page `<a href="#viewExamwiseStudentsReport?exam_id={{exa.model_exam_id}}&eName={{exa.model_exam_name}}&mMarks={{exa.model_exam_total_marks}}&time={{exa.model_exam_duration}}"><button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</button></a>`

Comment: by using your code, all `$routeParams` are showing `undefined`. i dont want them in URL but i want to use them in my JS file